# How to compare number of lines of two files using Awk

Tags: awk, text-processing, line-count

I am new to awk and need to compare the number of lines of two files.
The script shall return true,

```
if lines(f1) == (lines(f2)+1)
```

otherwise false. How can I do that?

Best regards

Comment: Normally you would use `wc -l` to count the lines in a file... failing that, have a look at Ed's answer here to see how to process 2 files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21280959/using-awk-to-process-two-different-files-consecutively

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has to be `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{x++} END{ if(x!=FNR){exit 1} }' file1 file2
```

The varibale `x` is incremented and contains the number of line of `file1` and FNR contains the number of `file2`. At the end, both are compared and the script is exited 0 or 1.

See an example:

```
user@host:~$ awk 'NR==FNR{x++} END{ if(x!=FNR){exit 1} }' shortfile longfile
user@host:~$ echo $?
1
user@host:~$ awk 'NR==FNR{x++} END{ if(x!=FNR){exit 1} }' samefile samefile
user@host:~$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: :-) Very succinct - have a vote. Actually, `awk` will exit with status zero naturally, so if you invert the logic and exit with status 1, you can omit the `exit 0`.

Comment: You could even just do `END{exit (x!=FNR)}` but maybe that's getting too obfuscated.

Comment: I think the required functionality is to return 1 when one file contains one more line than the other, not when both files contain the same number of lines, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should suit your purposes:

```
 [ oele3110 $] cat line_compare.awk
#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

NR==FNR{
    n_file1++;
}
NR!=FNR{
    n_file2++;
}

END{
    n_file2++;
    if(n_file1==n_file2){exit(1);}
}
 [ oele3110 $] cat f1
1
1
1
1
1
1
 [ oele3110 $] cat f2
1
1
1
1
1
 [ oele3110 $] cat f3
1
1
1
1
1
 [ oele3110 $]
 [ oele3110 $] wc -l f*
 6 f1
 5 f2
 5 f3
16 total
 [ oele3110 $] ./line_compare.awk f1 f2
 [ oele3110 $] echo $?
1
 [ oele3110 $] ./line_compare.awk  f2 f3
 [ oele3110 $] echo $?
0
 [ oele3110 $]
```

Actually, I think I should have asked you to invest a bit more effort before giving you the answer. I'll leave it for now, but next time I won't make the same mistake.